# How to find σ-fields in this question??

Tags: probability

Let $\Omega := \{ a,b,c,d \}$. Find three different $\sigma$-fields $f_{n}$ where $n = 0,1,2$ such that $f_{0} \subset f_{1} \subset f_{2}$.

Comment: This is not a homework solving site.

Comment: I am new to probability and I was not getting a right approach to start a question @TheGeekGreek

Comment: include your attempts

Comment: first of all can you find **one** $\sigma$-field?

Comment: Because you have said so little about what you know, it's hard to know what kind of help you need. Perhaps you do not understand what a $\sigma$-field is or you have a vague idea what it is but don't know how to construct any examples. That level of understanding would require a different kind of help than if you had already found two $\sigma$-fields, one a subset of the other, and just need the third one. But in order that we would know we were dealing with the second kind of question, you would have to show us your $\sigma$-fields and explain how you got them.

Comment: I don't know how to implement concept of σ
-field on questions. σ
-field is modeled event space which satisfies some conditions @DavidK

Comment: It sounds like your instructor has recited the formal definition of a $\sigma$-field to you but neglected to give even one non-trivial example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an obvious reason (don't mind), only a hint is provided: you can take $f_{0} := \{ \varnothing, \Omega \}$ and $f_{2} := 2^{\Omega}$.

Comment: Thanx for editing a question nd providing it a proper format.

Comment: @SupriyaChalotra, no problem. And you figure out an $f_{1}$ yet? :)

Comment: Naaa... I didn't understand how u got f2

Comment: The symbol $2^{\Omega}$ refers to the power set of $\Omega$, i.e. the collection of all subsets of $\Omega$. Now using the definition of sigma-algebra to prove  it.

Answer (score 0):

My hint is: given the set $\Omega_1 = \{ 1, 2, 3 \},$
create a $\sigma$-field over $\Omega_1$ that has a element
$\{ 1, 2\}$ but does *not* have an element $\{ 1 \}.$

You can use the properties of a $\sigma$-field to discover other subsets of $\Omega_1$ that this $\sigma$-field must include. Continue until no more subsets need to be added to the $\sigma$-field. Be careful not to include any subsets that you did not really need.

Then you may have a better understanding of how to construct various $\sigma$-fields over a set $\Omega,$ including the three $\sigma$-fields 
you need for your question.